# To test Ecommerce sorted items(High to Low price) are displaying properly or not using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Ecommerce application I have to test filtered items form Low to high price mean next item always should be greater than equal to previous one.
I have to compare same with selenium script and need to get result(PASS/FAIL) if all the items are displaying accordingly.
Below what I have written script for getting list of price on same page in one page there are 24 items but I don't have idea how to compare price. Please hlp me.

---

```
public class Price extends WebDriverCommonLib 
{   
@Test
  public void lowToHigh() throws InterruptedException

  {         
        Driver.driver.get("http://.....");
        Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='submit-form']//i[@class='fa fa-search']")).click();
        Select select = new Select(Driver.driver.findElement(By.name("product-sort")));
        select.selectByVisibleText("Price - Low to High");
        normalWait();
        java.util.List<WebElement> price = Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='find_prices']"));
        System.out.println(price.size());
        //List ourAl = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<price.size(); i=i+1) 
        {
        System.out.println(price.get(i).getText());          
        }           
  }
  }
```

Here I got output:

24

4.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
5.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
7.00

Answer (score 1):

1) First add all your price values into dynamic array list,

```
    ArrayList<Float> priceList = new ArrayList<Float>();
    for (int i = 0; i<price.size(); i=i+1) {
       priceList.add(Float.parseFloat(price.get(i).getText())); 
    }  
    if(!ascendingCheck(priceList)){
        Assert.fail("Not is ascending order");
    }
```

2)  And create below method to validate the order,

```
     Boolean ascendingCheck(ArrayList<Float> data){         
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size()-1; i++) {
            if (data.get(i) > data.get(i+1)) {
                return false;
            }       
         }
         return true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different approach. I would get all the prices in a list, sort the list, and then compare it to the original list. If the two lists are equal, then the list was sorted.

```
// scrape price elements
List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='find_prices']"));

// extract the prices from the price elements and store in a List
List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement e : price)
{
    prices.add(e.getText());
}

// make a copy of the list
List<String> sortedPrices = new ArrayList<String>(prices);

// sort the list
Collections.sort(sortedPrices);

// true if the prices are sorted
System.out.println(sortedPrices.equals(prices));
```

Comment: Hi JeffC, 


I am using your suggested code for price comparison but its not always giving correct  result. Like if price increasing Rs9.00 to Rs10.00 or Rs99.00 to Rs100.00 then its giving wrong output "False" but actually it has to be true.
I have to do price comparison along with pagination for multiple pages.
please help me how to sort price with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JeffC how about using junit or testng to do the assertion instead of printing the comparison?

```
assertEquals("Sorting low to high prices aint working.",prices, sortedPrices);
```